# Can't get Java enum that implements interface which extends another interface to compile

Tags: java, enums, compiler-bug

I want to create an enum that implements `I2`, which extends `I1`:

```
package a;

import static a.E1.E1A;
interface I1 extends I1 {}
interface I2 extends I1 {}
enum E1 implements I2 { E1A, A1B; }

class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        switch (E1A) {
            case E1A:
                System.out.println("it worked!");
        }
    }
}
```

It was working until I added `I1` and made `I2` extend `I1`. Now it works but it can't find E1A (the static was there before so that's not the issue):

```
$ javac A.java
A.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol  : static E1A
location: class a.E1
import static a.E1.E1A;
^


The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$18.visitClassType(Types.java:1630)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$18.visitClassType(Types.java:1620)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:568)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:3294)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.supertype(Types.java:1617)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:889)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:891)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:897)
    [...]
```

Why?

Comment: Does `symbol  : static E1A` exist in class `E1`?

Comment: Do zou really have interface I1 extends I1 {}?? seems like endless loop to me.

Comment: Please choose meaningful variable names, then this wouln't have happened. `A, I1, I2, E1` are not meaningful ...

Comment: @jlordo: I alpha-renamed it from my existing code, then produced a minimal example. i.e, they **were** meaningful in my real code.

Comment: @Dog: Don't do that. If you really have to, choose meaningful substitutions. It's good that you produced a minimal example, even an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), just the names make it really confusing...

Comment: @jlordo: Every time I choose meaningful names, people argue against the code, because the names don't make perfect sense. Here you go: pastebin.com/k2KyxjYS Are you happy?

Comment: @Dog: That `interface Animal extends Animal` jumped right into my eye ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get this with Javac 1.7.0_15

```
C:\Users\Andry\test>javac a\A.java
a\A.java:4: error: cyclic inheritance involving I1
interface I1 extends I1 {}
^
1 error
```

Your code is wrong (an interface can't extend itself), but you probably have found a bug in javac!

Comment: oh.. it's because I copied the line and forgot to remove extends in I1.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you declare E1.E1A and, in the same file, import what you define.

Comment: That's the only way you get to refer to `E1A` in the code without prefixing it with its enum type